# QGIS/SAGA Cross-tabulation error

Tags: qgis, saga, change-detection

I'm new to **QGIS** after using **ESRI/ENVI/ERDAS** products for years. I am trying calculate a cross-tabulated change image for post-classification change detection. After figuring out how to fix a misalignment issue, I entered my input grids, which are 8-bit integer tifs.  However, when I try to execute the function, it fails to generate the change products.
I have a few hypotheses:

1. wrong layer types (e.g. not somehow flagged as classification
   output)
2. install problem (says something about SAGA folder not    found)
3. misspecification of the number of classes. I have 12 classes, but there is also a mysterious 255 class (which used to be no-data). I'm not sure what to enter.
4. Mac issue/QGIS compatibility issues: OS X 10.10.5 (14F2109) & QGIS 2.18.2
5. (and always the most likely) I'm doing something dumb.

Below are the log windows:

```
Algorithm Cross-classification and tabulation starting...
io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -INTERPOL 0 -GRIDS "/var/folders/8y/6924gdvx3jg6k2rz5yrzwz100000gr/T/processing6d4bd5aad86b4a63878cdad8f1dd4364/6cc17d2bb4d347c8bf52aa8f1b77716f/LC2000.sgrd" -FILES "/Users/Tom (new)/Dropbox/NicaGIS/ChangeDetection72/c72_uso2000re/w001001.adf"
io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -INTERPOL 0 -GRIDS "/var/folders/8y/6924gdvx3jg6k2rz5yrzwz100000gr/T/processing6d4bd5aad86b4a63878cdad8f1dd4364/ae1feeedf5db45318f64f76d8909ce91/LC2000.sgrd" -FILES "/Users/Tom (new)/Dropbox/NicaGIS/ChangeDetection72/c72_uso2000re/w001001.adf"
grid_analysis "Cross-Classification and Tabulation" -INPUT "/var/folders/8y/6924gdvx3jg6k2rz5yrzwz100000gr/T/processing6d4bd5aad86b4a63878cdad8f1dd4364/ae1feeedf5db45318f64f76d8909ce91/LC2000.sgrd" -INPUT2 "/var/folders/8y/6924gdvx3jg6k2rz5yrzwz100000gr/T/processing6d4bd5aad86b4a63878cdad8f1dd4364/ae1feeedf5db45318f64f76d8909ce91/LC2000.sgrd" -MAXNUMCLASS 12 -RESULTGRID "/var/folders/8y/6924gdvx3jg6k2rz5yrzwz100000gr/T/processing6d4bd5aad86b4a63878cdad8f1dd4364/8d5691d31a5442e1ac4c1d3f5aa1bd3b/RESULTGRID.sdat" -RESULTTABLE "/var/folders/8y/6924gdvx3jg6k2rz5yrzwz100000gr/T/processing6d4bd5aad86b4a63878cdad8f1dd4364/02dace88c2d84c11b2040c0ca71cebe7/RESULTTABLE.csv"
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `new'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `/Users/Tom (new)/.qgis2//processing/saga_batch_job.sh'
Converting outputs
Loading resulting layers

The following layers were not correctly generated.
Cross-Classification Grid
Cross-Tabulation Table
You can check the log messages to find more information about the execution of the algorithm

****************
```

Other log window -- not sure the differences:

```
2017-03-11T17:02:00 1   Specified SAGA folder does not exist. Will try to find built-in binaries.
2017-03-11T17:02:00 1   Specified SAGA folder does not exist. Will try to find built-in binaries.
2017-03-11T17:02:00 0   SAGA execution commands
            io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -INTERPOL 0 -GRIDS "/var/folders/8y/6924gdvx3jg6k2rz5yrzwz100000gr/T/processing6d4bd5aad86b4a63878cdad8f1dd4364/6cc17d2bb4d347c8bf52aa8f1b77716f/LC2000.sgrd" -FILES "/Users/Tom (new)/Dropbox/NicaGIS/ChangeDetection72/c72_uso2000re/w001001.adf"
            io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -INTERPOL 0 -GRIDS "/var/folders/8y/6924gdvx3jg6k2rz5yrzwz100000gr/T/processing6d4bd5aad86b4a63878cdad8f1dd4364/ae1feeedf5db45318f64f76d8909ce91/LC2000.sgrd" -FILES "/Users/Tom (new)/Dropbox/NicaGIS/ChangeDetection72/c72_uso2000re/w001001.adf"
            grid_analysis "Cross-Classification and Tabulation"  -INPUT "/var/folders/8y/6924gdvx3jg6k2rz5yrzwz100000gr/T/processing6d4bd5aad86b4a63878cdad8f1dd4364/ae1feeedf5db45318f64f76d8909ce91/LC2000.sgrd" -INPUT2 "/var/folders/8y/6924gdvx3jg6k2rz5yrzwz100000gr/T/processing6d4bd5aad86b4a63878cdad8f1dd4364/ae1feeedf5db45318f64f76d8909ce91/LC2000.sgrd" -MAXNUMCLASS 12 -RESULTGRID "/var/folders/8y/6924gdvx3jg6k2rz5yrzwz100000gr/T/processing6d4bd5aad86b4a63878cdad8f1dd4364/8d5691d31a5442e1ac4c1d3f5aa1bd3b/RESULTGRID.sdat" -RESULTTABLE "/var/folders/8y/6924gdvx3jg6k2rz5yrzwz100000gr/T/processing6d4bd5aad86b4a63878cdad8f1dd4364/02dace88c2d84c11b2040c0ca71cebe7/RESULTTABLE.csv"
2017-03-11T17:02:00 0   SAGA execution console output
            /bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `new'
            /bin/sh: -c: line 0: `/Users/Tom (new)/.qgis2//processing/saga_batch_job.sh'
2017-03-11T17:02:00 2   Error loading result layer:
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/gui/Postprocessing.py", line 75, in handleAlgorithmResults
                out.name))
              File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/dataobjects.py", line 199, in load
                + '\nCheck the processing framework log to look for errors')
            RuntimeError: Could not load layer: /var/folders/8y/6924gdvx3jg6k2rz5yrzwz100000gr/T/processing6d4bd5aad86b4a63878cdad8f1dd4364/8d5691d31a5442e1ac4c1d3f5aa1bd3b/RESULTGRID.sdat
            Check the processing framework log to look for errors

2017-03-11T17:02:00 2   Error loading result layer:
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/gui/Postprocessing.py", line 75, in handleAlgorithmResults
                out.name))
              File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/dataobjects.py", line 199, in load
                + '\nCheck the processing framework log to look for errors')
            RuntimeError: Could not load layer: /var/folders/8y/6924gdvx3jg6k2rz5yrzwz100000gr/T/processing6d4bd5aad86b4a63878cdad8f1dd4364/02dace88c2d84c11b2040c0ca71cebe7/RESULTTABLE.csv
            Check the processing framework log to look for errors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'll wager it's the space in the file path (between Tom and new). The following error seems to hint at it

```
syntax error near unexpected token `new'
```

In some versions of processing, the file path isn't surrounded with quotes when building up the command line to run saga/grass, so path names containing spaces become a problem.

I think this is (largely) fixed as of 2.18, but may still exist in some places.

As a rule of thumb, avoid using spaces in file/directory names (and in some cases, layer names). If you need spaces in file names for readability, replace them with underscores instead.